# Ajax in devise Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am currently doing a project, and I am using `Devise` for the `User Authentication`. I have the `before_action :authenticate_user!`in my `Post Controller`. When I click `new post` without `Signing in` it redirects to the `Log in` Page. That's fine, But I want it to be as pop over(when I click the `new post`,the `log in` form must popover). How can I achieve this. I have also referred to this

[Rails 4 Devise Login as a POPUP window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848139/rails-4-devise-login-as-a-popup-window)

But, still when I clicked the `new Post`, it is redirecting to the `sign in` page.
Help me with this issue, Thanks in advance.

I have this code in my Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController is

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController


respond_to :json

  def create
    session['user_auth'] = params[:user]
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")

sign_in(resource_name, resource)
message = I18n.t 'devise.sessions.signed_in'

yield resource if block_given?

if request.xhr?
 return render :json => {:success => true, :login => true, :data =>  {:message => message}}
else
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end


end

  def failure
    user = User.where(email: session['user_auth'][:email]).first rescue nil
    message = I18n.t 'devise.failure.invalid', authentication_keys: "email"

respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render :json => {:success => false, :data => {:message => message, :cause => 'invalid'} }
  }
  format.html {
    redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
  }
end


end
end
```

Comment: have you tried generating devise controllers and overriding the `sign_in` action?

Comment: Yep! I used `rails generate devise:controllers users -c=sessions` to generate the controller, and changed the routes, and customized the code in the controller, but still no magic, it is again redirecting.

Comment: can you please post the controller code?

Comment: I have added the sessions controller code in the Post.